# plug-in for MOODLE

Tags: moodle, plugins

How can i add a plug-in that i developed in [MOODLE](http://moodle.org), considering the fact that MOODLE is an open source project?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the [documentation](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Installing_contributed_modules_or_plugins) on installing contributed modules to moodle.  You have to be approved before your plugins are available to everybody.  If you wanted to get your plugin added as a core component, you should contact the development team.  Make sure you follow the [guidelines](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development:Guidelines_for_contributed_code) for your contributed code.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [guidelines for contributed code](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Development:Guidelines_for_contributed_code). They should include everything you need to know about contributing to the moodle project. They describe that you have to submit it on their bugtracker, etc. -- for further question, I suggest you contact the moodle people directly.

Answer (score 1):

The code checker plug in developed by the Open University ([moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=local_codechecker](http://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=local_codechecker)) is an invaluable tool for anyone hoping to contribute an extension to Moodle and incorporates general coding good practice.

I would recommend using this for any software you are planning to share with other Moodle users and using the forums at moodle.org to get some feedback on beta versions and your concept while developing your plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Moodle contributes code guidelines.

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Guidelines_for_contributed_code#How_to_submit_code

Read the **How to request that your code be tested/reviewed** section.

Pay particular attention to following the moodle API

http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Coding